# TeamCity API - how to filter build queue by buildTypeId

Tags: api, filtering, teamcity

i'm using Team City api to get nice build queue items and if I call it like this:
https://corpo.teamcity.com/app/rest/buildQueue

it gives me somrthing like this:

```
<builds count="151" href="/app/rest/buildQueue">
<build id="9564366" buildTypeId="App_Docker_Thor" state="queued" branchName="<default>" defaultBranch="true" href="/app/rest/buildQueue/id:9564366" webUrl="https://corpo.teamcity.com/viewQueued.html?itemId=9564366"/>
</builds>
```

so my goal is to filter build queue by buildTypeId using contains or starts-with filter.

I have hard time to set filter correctly, for sure exact match is working fine like so:
https://corpo.teamcity.com/app/rest/buildQueue?locator=buildType:(id:App_Docker_Thor)

Can it be done (and how construct such filter) or filtering should be implemented on client side ?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, TeamCity REST API doesn't allow to use wildcards in locators. So yes, you should filter request's result on client side.

P.S. For me it's more convenient to parse JSON instead of XML. You could set "Accept: application/json" header to get JSON reply.